# How do I revoke access token in Ciscospark

Tags: cisco

I was trying to find the URI for revoking the access token for Ciscospark. But, revoke URI is not present in any of the cisco spark documents.

Can anyone provide me the URI or tell me how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

This is discussed here:

https://collaborationhelp.cisco.com/article/en-us/DOC-19842

> 1. From the customer view in https:/​/​admin.ciscospark.com, go to
>      Users and select a person.
> 2. Click Roles and Security and click Reset Access. The Cisco Spark app
>      automatically signs them out, this can take up to 6 hours. You can
>      delete a user to remove their access immediately.